# VBA REGEX MS ACCESS

Tags: regex, vba, regex-lookarounds

I am using MS Access to implement regex
I wish to find everything after the ")" in a statement but excluding the bracket itself

I use the following Regex

```
strPart3 = regexp(StringToCheck, "(?<=\)).*", False)
```

Where the function is

```
Function regexp(StringToCheck As Variant, PatternToUse As String, Optional, CaseSensitive As Boolean = True)

  Dim re As New regexp
  re.Pattern = PatternToUse
  re.Global = False
  re.IgnoreCase = Not CaseSensitive
  Dim m
  For Each m In re.Execute(StringToCheck)
    regexp = m.Value
  Next

End Function
```

I get an error from MS Access saying

Method Execute of object IREGExp2 failed
I think this is because MS Access doesn't support look behinds based on a previous thred i opened up

Can anyone suggest an alternative way (preferably in regex as im using this project to learn it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the Regex code

```
strPart3 = regexp(StringToCheck, "[^/)]*$", False)
```

gives me exactly what i was looking for